# server client chatroom program in java shows Address already in use

Tags: java, networking, server, client, chat

I am new to networking and I am trying to write the server client program. Still, I keep getting Address already in use and cant chat. A friend of mine run this in his pc and it was working. Can somebody explain to me why I keep getting this error?

Here is the server class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class server
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(8001);
        System.out.println("Server up and listening:");
        Socket S = serv.accept();
        InetAddress obj = S.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("Request coming from:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S.getInputStream()));
        String msg = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message recieved:"+msg);
        br.close();
        serv.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

Here is the client class:

```
import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
  class client`{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Socket s = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
    InetAddress obj = null;


    try {

        obj = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);  
        s = new Socket(obj, 8001);
        String str = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        byte[] arr = str.getBytes();
        bout = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        bout.write(arr);
        bout.flush();
        bout.close();
        s.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
} }
```

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Have you checked whether the port is already in use like the error states?

Comment: In client, what parameter are you sending as argument?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

use below command to determine if you have any open port on the machine where you are running your Server program

```
netstat -nao | find "8001"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change 8001 to another value. It looks like that it is under use by another program. Depends on your operating system, there are plenty ways to learn which ports are occupied.

Comment: hey tried that already several times with ports between 8000 to 8010. still it doesnt work...

Comment: how can I find out which ports are occupied?